# Why is my if statement testing floating point values always false?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

```
import xlrd

file_path = r"C:\Users\Allen\Desktop\数据曲线.xlsx"
table = xlrd.open_workbook(file_path).sheet_by_index(2)
data_current = table.col_values(4)[1:]
data_time = table.col_values(2)[1:]
time_start = []
for i in data_current:
    index = data_current.index(i)
    if float(i) < 0.1 and float(data_current[index+1]) > 1:
        print('come on!')
    else:
        print('a')
```

My input:

```
data_current = ['0.0', '0.0', '1.44']
```

This is just an example, but the real data follows the same structure.

Why is my output always `a`, and never `come on!`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data_current.index(i)` will return the **first** match, so for `'0.0'` `index` is always going to be `0`.

Use the [`enumerate()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to provide a running index instead:

```
for index, i in enumerate(data_current):
```

Take into account that `index + 1` can be *outside* of the range of valid indices.